# Microsoft Cognitive Services add a person returns status 500

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using Mircosoft Cognitive Services' Face API and when using the add person face API (Under Person) in particular, cognitive services returns a status 500 with a message saying "unspecified". Does anyone know how to resolve this?

The following is my POST request:

```js
POST https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/fyp-prototype/persons/6CB8C802-370B-4034-9B95-965B760F2F43/persistedFaces HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
    "url":"http://i.imgur.com/H0nYHTq.jpg"
}
```

The following is the return message from cognitive services:

```js
{
  "error": {
"code": "Unspecified",
"message": "Internal server error"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b

Comment: Hi, just want to ensure whether this problems still continues. I suppose it might be some temporary error.

Comment: @XuanHu I managed to fix the issue already. Turns out that when I am trying to consume the addFace API, I supplied a personId that is fully capitalized. Seemingly, the personId is case sensitive, hence, the API request failed.

Comment: Good to know. Actually the personId is a system generated Guid, so it is recommended to handle it as Guid rather than raw string.

Comment: @XuanHu Yes, we set our models to store the personId in uppercase, therefore, the GUID mismatch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just want to clarify a little more about the Guid as Guid wins both on speed and storage, it is treated more like a number and only consumes 16 bytes which is much smaller than a string with 32 characters.